# C# Xamarin Async Task in Loop within an Async Task

Tags: c#, xamarin, async-await, task

I think I have a racing issue and can't solve it myself.

In Xamarin Android I'm getting data from Azure SQL and trying to update a local SQLite db in a loop.

Here's the code:

```
        foreach (var hotItem in updatedData)
        {
            var updated = await vendorController.ContainsVideoUrlAndUpdate(hotItem, date);

            if (!updated)
                await vendorController.AddUpdatedData(hotItem);
        }


        public async Task<bool> ContainsVideoUrlAndUpdate(List<VideoItem> updateDataList, DateTime lastDateUpdated) {
        try
        {
            foreach (VideoItem v in updateDataList)
            {
                ***WORKS ONLY FIRST ITERATION****var containsList = (await Conn.Table<VideoItem>().Where(o => (o.VideoURL == v.VideoURL && o.ZipCode == v.ZipCode) || (o.VideoURL == v.VideoURL && o.CityWide == true)).ToListAsync());****************
                if (containsList != null && containsList.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var currData in containsList)
                    {
                        currData.LastUpdated = lastDateUpdated.ToString();
                        await Conn.UpdateAsync(currData);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    await Conn.InsertAsync(v);
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
        catch (SQLiteException ex)
        {
            Log.Info("Exception Updating LocalVideoList.sqlite DB", ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The line I marked ***WORKS ONLY FIRST ITERATION**** only works the first iteration of the loop. Even though I have 10 test records in the SQLite db that match the 10 records being searched for in that line, only the first one is found. The other 9 fail.

I think it must have something to do with the async task but I can't seem to fix it.  What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:
To clarify, the line I marked out works the first time -- it finds the match in the SQLite DB; the other nine iterations it does not find a match even though those records exist in the SQLite DB.

```
 if (containsList != null && containsList.Count > 0)
```

returns count = 0 on the second and subsequent loops, so instead of updating the existing record in SQLite db, it runs:

```
await Conn.InsertAsync(v);
```

resulting in duplicate records being inserted in the SQLite DB instead of updating the lastupdatedate field in the existing records.

I used an SQLite db Firefox plug in to use the same query for all 10 records and the query finds all 10 records so it is not the query.  Is it possible that when it loops the second and subsequent times that the ascyn task is locking it out? There are no exceptions.

Comment: when "the other 9 fail" please edit your question and explain how they are failing. You get a exception? The program locks up? What?

Comment: I updated the original post. The 9 iterations it fails on is not because of the query.

Comment: Could this be a threading problem?

Comment: So what's the -1 for? Is this a stupid question or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I had hired a contractor to do the first SQLite database work and I finally saw he added a unique constraint (primary key) on the VendorID field of the SQLite table which was not a unique value field. Hence when posting the update data it didn't post 10 records but 1 record 10 times. When the update loop ran, it found all 10 records in the first iteration, updated all 10, and then couldn't find the other 9 records because they simply were not there. It added 9 records each time the program ran, and on because of the wrong primary key restraint, it again added the same record multiple times. If the code looks right and should work, look at those things you think are 'correct' first. If the light goes out, you don't rip out the walls checking the wiring, you check the light bulb first, right?